# syntax error, unexpected '?' in my laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use sharing host to run may laravel app but it give's me this error in error_log

laravel files in directory I called it host

public folder in subdomain it name is gardenfilm.studioaleph.com

error log say's:

> [11-May-2019 07:18:08 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected
>   '?' in
>   /home/studioaleph/host/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 500

```
if (! function_exists('factory')) {
    /**
     * Create a model factory builder for a given class, name, and amount.
     *
     * @param  dynamic  class|class,name|class,amount|class,name,amount
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder
     */
    function factory()
    {
        $factory = app(EloquentFactory::class);

        $arguments = func_get_args();

        if (isset($arguments[1]) && is_string($arguments[1])) {
            return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null);
        } elseif (isset($arguments[1])) {
            return $factory->of($arguments[0])->times($arguments[1]);
        }

        return $factory->of($arguments[0]);
    }
}
```

this line is problem :

```
return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null);
```

PHP Version 5.6.32

Laravel Framework 5.8.16

Comment: As far as I can tell - from the [Laravel 5.8 installation page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation) you need PHP >= 7.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salaam. This error occurs when you use PHP < 7.0. You have to use PHP > 7.0.

You can read more about this [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). It's called `Null coalescing operator`.

And the system requirement for Laravel 5.8 says you must use PHP >= 7.1.3. [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#server-requirements).